# Ajax upload one file at a time?

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, upload

So I have an upload form with one input file field to upload images to my server, however I need to send only one image at a time, for example, the user selects 50 images in the same file input field I want it to be sent one image at a time and for each image the Ajax will make a new request to the server. Gave to understand? anyone know how to do?

I've seen some plugins that do this but do not solve my problem completely I wanted to know how to do the 0 as separates each image that was selected and send one at a time to the server.

Comment: So you can select multiple files with a default file-typed <input>? To my knowledge, you can only select one file at a time with it and submit this single file at a time.

Comment: I want to do something like this, http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php , however I'm not getting to understand the logic of it and the plugin it does not meet my need for 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the default `<input type="file">` control allows one file selected at a time, so you can only upload one file at a time. However, I recently met the requirement to allow users to select a folder and upload the files within that folder (one by one) and I find a solution (sorry but I didn't keep the solution url). Here is what I do:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple="" webkitdirectory="">
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-warning pull-left" onclick="uploadFiles()">
        <small class="pull-left result_text">Choose a file folder which only contains image files.</small>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var File_Lists;
window.onload = function(){
    var output = document.getElementById('output');

    // Detect when the value of the files input changes.
    document.getElementById('files').onchange = function(e) {
        // Retrieve the file list from the input element
        File_Lists=e.target.files;
        // Outputs file names to div id "output"
        output.innerText = "";
        var MAX_ROWS=5;
        var filenum=File_Lists.length;
        for (i=0; i<Math.min(filenum, MAX_ROWS); i++){
            output.innerText  = output.innerText + e.target.files[i].webkitRelativePath+"\n";
        }
        if(filenum>MAX_ROWS){
            output.innerText = output.innerText + " and other "+(filenum-MAX_ROWS)+" files...";
        }
    }
}


function uploadFiles(){
    var files=File_Lists;
    // Create a new HTTP requests, Form data item (data we will send to the server) and an empty string for the file paths.
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    data = new FormData();
    paths = "";

    // Set how to handle the response text from the server
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(ev){
        //handle with server-side responses
    };

    // Loop through the file list
    for (var i in files){
        // Append the current file path to the paths variable (delimited by tripple hash signs - ###)
        paths += files[i].webkitRelativePath+"###";
        // Append current file to our FormData with the index of i
        data.append(i, files[i]);
    };
    // Append the paths variable to our FormData to be sent to the server
    // Currently, As far as I know, HTTP requests do not natively carry the path data
    // So we must add it to the request manually.
    data.append('paths', paths);

    // Open and send HHTP requests to upload.php
    xhr.open('POST', "process_upload_photo.php", true);
    xhr.send(this.data);
}
```

I use PHP for the server side. You can get the file paths with following code, and do similar things as it is uploading a single file.

```
$paths = explode("###",rtrim($_POST['paths'],"###"));
```